# How can I get telnet on my macbook pro with High Sierra

Tags: command-line, high-sierra

Telnet is not available on High Sierra. I don't have the option to copy the telnet source folder from another mac and I'm wondering where/how I can get a legitimate copy of telnet.

Edit
I'm looking for a copy from a source outside of homebrew or macports

Comment: Why not homebrew/macports - this reason might limit other solutions especially as you  can't copy the source folder

Comment: I have had trouble with homebrew/macports in the past. Somehow the install becomes corrupt and I have to reinstall all my previous packages. I don't like how the permissions are managed also.

Comment: Check this guide out: https://medium.com/ayuth/bring-telnet-back-on-macos-high-sierra-11de98de1544

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I searched through Apple support forums and found an answer that I believe will help others reinstall ftp and telnet on Mac High Sierra.

Navigate to [www.gnu.org/software/inetutils/](http://www.gnu.org/software/inetutils/)
Click on the HTTP download link for "Inetutils"
Download "inetutils-1.9.4.tar.gz"
tar zxvf inetutils-1.9.4.tar.gz

Direct ftp site -> http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/inetutils/

```
cd inetutils-1.9.4
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

telnet x.x.x.x port

I found the answer at this forum
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/79056

Comment: @BradParks The solution required that homebrew and/or macports not be used

Comment: You can install telnet through brew as well. https://brewInstall.org is a webapp to search for a mac app and get the steps to install the app. To install telnet run the following command. But make sure you have homebrew installed.
`brew install telnet`